# Throttling limit on Azure IOT Hub file uploads

Tags: azure

We are having 6000 devices and these devices need to upload file at 12:10 PM CST everyday.
All devices are located in CST.
We are getting exception

```
"could not upload the file {"Message":"{\"errorCode\":429003,\"trackingId\":\"fdc25df8367f40ed8fdb305f40b7412e-G:7-TimeStamp:04/14/2019 13:19:17\",\"message\":\"The request has been throttled. Wait 10 seconds and try again. Operation type: FileUploadRequest\",\"timestampUtc\":\"2019-04-14T13:19:17.9684843Z\"}","ExceptionMessage":""}"
```

As we checked the throttling limit for file upload there is no such limits mentioned. However they mentioned throttling limits only on notification messages.

We already disabled file upload notification messages but still getting above exception. Please can you recommend on how to proceed with this scenario.

We are using standard tier (S2) and 3 units. We don't have plans to move to S3 tier as of now.